# Invalid argument exception in socket.accept() if I restart immediately after a previous run quit

Tags: python, sockets

I have a client server architecture written in python. Most of the time it works fine, but sometimes, after I stop the server and restart it immediately afterwards, I get the following error:

**Accept failed due to : 22 Message Invalid argument, error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument**

*However*, if I wait a few minutes and the start the same script again with no changes it works fine.

This is the loop I use on the server to accept incoming connections from clients:

```
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('',port))
    s.listen(1)
except:
    #logError()

while True:
    try:
        conn, address = s.accept() #THIS ACCEPT FAILS SOMETIMES
        multiprocessing.Process(target=HandleConnection, args=(conn, address, messageQueue, taskQueue, IOLock, numberOfConnections, numberOfConnectionsLock,resultsDirectory)).start()
    except socket.error, msg:
      #logError()  -> this except catches the error
```

Does the port get blocked for some time after I run the server? If so, is there are way to query if the port is blocked and wait until it's unblocked if I want to start the server up again immediately after it just quit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set `SO_REUSEADDR` before binding.

```
setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

Failing to do so may prevent the socket from binding, thus the error when `accept`ing. You would have noticed this error if you hadn't choked exceptions in the first block.

Comment: I wasn't chocking the exception, I was logging it, but I guess I should have returned after it. Instead I got into the while loop, which filled my logs up with garbage and I thought there was an issue with accept and not with bind. Frustrating.

Comment: @Alexander Oh I see. Sorry if my comment sounded snarky, it's totally understandable to miss a warning with so many others.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I got downvoted and I was like 'omg, I'm not trying to ask a stupid question, I've been at this for hours now'. Thanks so much for your help.