# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument in python3 socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have a problem with socket programming in Python 3. I get an exception that is not making the program crash, but is just shown in terminal.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from imigui import Ui_MainWindow

class imiserv(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    send_msg = pyqtSignal('QString', 'QString')

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Sport_lineEdit.setMaxLength(5)
        self.ui.Sconnect_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.serv)

        self.send_msg.connect(self.write_msg)

    def write_msg(self, lbl_msg= None, txt_msg= None):
        if lbl_msg:
            self.ui.C_label.setText(lbl_msg)
        if txt_msg:
            self.ui.Clog_textEdit.setText(txt_msg)

    def serv(self):
        MY_LOCK = threading.Lock()
        class CountT(threading.Thread):
            def __init__(self, parent):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self._parent= parent

            def run(self):
                MY_LOCK.acquire()
                self._parent.send_msg.emit("Waiting connections","")
                while True:
                    cliconn, (addr, remoport)= self._parent.clis.accept()
                    clirecmsg= str(cliconn.recv(1024)
                    self._parent.send_msg.emit("{0}:{1} is connected.".format(addr, remoport), "{0}:{1}".format(addr, remoport)
                    cliconn.close()

                MY_LOCK.release()

        try:
            self.clis= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.clis.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            clierhost= str(self.ui.Sip_lineEdit.text())
            clierport= int(self.ui.Sport_lineEdit.text())
            self.clis.bind((clierhost, clierport))
            self.clis.listen(5)
            a= CountT(self)
            a.daemon= True
            a.start()
        except socket.error as err:
            err= str(err)
            print(err)
```

And here are the errors that happened decussate (this error show only in linux os):

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "imiclilap.py", line 34, in run
    cliconn, (addr, remoport)= self._parent.clis.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 135, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "imiclilap.py", line 34, in run
    cliconn, (addr, remoport)= self._parent.clis.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 135, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862742/invalid-argument-exception-in-socket-accept-if-i-restart-immediately-after-a-p

Comment: The code you posted can't be the code you have run: 1. it contains a syntax error; 2. it only starts one thread, not two; 3. `accept()` may raise "invalid argument" only if you have not called `listen()`.

Comment: You are calling `accept()` on a socket that hasn't been put into LISTEN state, but not with this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UDP socket sendto() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268008/udp-socket-sendto-functions)

Answer (score 0):

here is a detailed answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30268744/8447510

in short: use 192.168.1.x instead of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score -3):

Errorno 22 is a linux error defined as "Invalid Argument" so its possible your address or port are not the correct types. Check that

> addr, remoport

are string, int respectively.

Its also possible you have already bound to the socket in a different thread.

You could run your program in strace [1](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) that would allow to you to see what sockets are getting used and if there is some double binding going on.

Also just a fyi:

Your program is not crashing because the error happens in a separate thread so that thread is crashing but your main thread is still going.