# UDP socket sendto() functions

Tags: python, sockets, sendto

I get an error if I want to write on my udp socket like this.
According to the docu there shouldn't be a problem.
I don't understand why bind() works well in the same way but sendto() fails.

```
udp_port = 14550
udp_server  = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_server.bind(('127.0.0.1', udp_port))
udp_clients = {}
```

Error:

```
udp_server.sendto('', ('192.0.0.1', 14550) )
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: can you paste some more context? Have you called bind()?

Comment: added the binding code part

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error says that you have an invalid argument. When reading your code, I can say that the offending argument is the IP address :

- you bind your socket to `127.0.0.1`
- you try to send data to `192.0.0.1` that is **on another network**

If you want to send data to a host at IP address `192.0.0.1`, bind the socket to a local network interface on same network, or on a network that can find a route to `192.0.0.1`

I have a (private) local network at `192.168.56.*`, if I bind the socket to `192.168.56.x` (x being local address), I can send data to `192.168.56.y` (y being the address of the server) ; but if I bind to `127.0.0.1` I get the `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 3):

Your bind call should not be binding to the loopback address. Try doing this:

```
udp_server.bind(('0.0.0.0', udp_port))
```

Comment: for reference, this will set the source port (udp_port) and will not set the source address. the address field will then get filled in by your network stack automatically once it figures out which interface/address to use based on the system's routing tables.

Answer (score 2):

Client:

```
sock_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_client.sendto("message", ("127.0.0.1", 4444))
```

Server:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4444))
while(1):
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print "received:", data
```

This code works. Python-2.7.

It seems you mixed client and server sockets, addresses or subnetworks.